# I'm not able to enter float data in my database

Tags: android

Following is the code that is not working beacuse I tried to enter float into the database.

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_VARIABLES+"("
            +"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "Crop_Name TEXT,"
            + "Temp_Max REAL,"
            + "Temp_Min REAL,"
            + "Humidity_Max REAL,"
            + "Humidity_Min REAL,"
            + "PH_Max REAL,"
            + "PH_Min REAL,"
            + "Rain REAL,"

            +"Time_To_Harvest INTEGER,"

            + "Sunshine_Days INTEGER);");
```

i have entered data into the table using a method as follows

```
insert_Data(db,"Rice",35,20,80,60,(float)6.5,(float)5.0,1400,150,6);
        insert_Data(db,"Wheat",12,30,60,50,(float)3.7,7,310,120,6);
```

and the method is as follows

```
private void insert_Data(SQLiteDatabase db,String name,float tempmax,float tempmin,float humiditymax,
                             float humidity_min,float phmax,float phmin,float rainmax,
                             int T2H,int Sunshine){

       ContentValues crop_data= new ContentValues();
        crop_data.put("Crop_Name",name);
        crop_data.put("Temp_Max",tempmax);
        crop_data.put("Temp_Min",tempmin);
        crop_data.put("Humidity_Max",humiditymax);
        crop_data.put("Humidity_Min",humidity_min);
        crop_data.put("PH_Max",phmax);
        crop_data.put("PH_Min",phmin);
        crop_data.put("Rain",rainmax);

        crop_data.put("Time_To_Harvest",T2H);
        crop_data.put("Sunshine)Days",Sunshine);
        db.insert("variables",null,crop_data);
```

data is not being inserted when i run this code. but when i replace all the float data in this method with integers data is inserted.

sorry this question was due to my mistake.

Comment: how did you check that it is not being inserted? please read your code there is typo ...

Comment: I added android database manager to my project and checked

Comment: where is the typo? i didnt see any in my code

Comment: `Sunshine)Days` in `insert_Data`

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

Read http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html to more info.

You are having typo. **Sunshine)Days**

Try with double data type instead of float!!!